# Question on the definition of outward normal vector from Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

The following definition of the outward unit normal at the boundary of a manifold $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is taken from Spivak, *Calculus on manifolds* (page 119).

> If $M$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold-with-boundary and $x \in \partial M$, then $(\partial M)_x$ is a $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace of the $k$-dimensional vector space $M_x$. Thus there are exactly two unit vectors in $M_x$ which are perpendicular to $(\partial M)_x$; they can be distinguished as follows: If $f : W \to \mathbb R^n$ is a coordinate system with $W \subseteq H^k$ and $f(0) = x$, then only one of these vectors is $f_{\ast}(v_0)$ for some $v_0$ with $v^k < 0$. This unit vector is called the *outward unit vector*.

What wonders me is how a coordinate system is defined according to the book. If $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is $k$-dimensional manifold, then for each $x \in M$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$, an open set $W \subseteq \mathbb R^k$, and a 1-1 differentiable function $f : W \to \mathbb R^n$ such that

(1) $f(W) = M \cap U$

(2) $f'(y)$ has rank $k$ for each $y \in W$,

(3) $f^{-1} : f(W) \to W$ is continuous.

This $f : W \to \mathbb R^n$ is called a *coordinate system*. As $H^k := \{ x \in \mathbb R^k : x^k \ge 0 \}$ is not open, if $W \subseteq H^k$ and $x \in \partial M$, then as $W$ does not touches the boundardy of $H^k$ (i.e those points $x$ with $x^k = 0$) the condition $f(0) = x$ implies $0 \notin W$ and so $x \notin M \cap U$. But by the requirement $x \in U$. So this gives a contradiction?

Have I understood something wrong here? I guess this might be an error in the book, and I think to fix it the definition of a coordinate system $f : W \to \mathbb R^n$ must be altered to account for boundary points, i.e. I guess what would work is if $x$ is not a boundary point, then the conditions are as above, and if $x \in \partial M$ to alter (1) to

(1') $f(W \cap H^k) = M \cap U$

(guess the others could also be restricted to $W \cap H^k$, but I guess leaving them would also be fine). But after this alteration the assertion ''$W \subseteq H^k$'' has to be dropped or we would still get the same contradictions for $W$ open in $\mathbb R^k$.

So am I right in my objections? And how would you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall being puzzled by this as well. Look at page 113, where condition M' is described. Spivak says that a set is called a manifold with boundary if every point has a neighborhood in which condition M (from a few pages earlier) holds, OR a neighborhood in which condition M' holds (which maps a relatively open subset of half-space to the interior-and-boundary around the point).

In particular, this means that a "manifold-with-boundary" is not a "manifold", which seems (as English goes) to be crazy.

But we have lots of other cases of this in mathematics -- a skew-field is not necessarily a field, for instance. (We also see examples in other domains: a madonna-with-child is not a madonna, for instance, at least not if you're thinking of the painting or sculpture rather than the thing depicted.)

POST-COMMENT ADDITION

A manifold with boundary is divided into two subsets (see last sentence of page 113): the *boundary*, denoted $\partial M$, consisting of points $x$ satisfying condition M', and the interior, consisting of points satisfying condition M. (It requires a bit of work to show that these are in fact disjoint, that's what the last paragraph on P 113 does.)

The definition of outward normal applies *only to points $x$ of the boundary $\partial M$*, i.e., those satisfying condition M'.

Theorem 5.2 shows how to get a "coordinate system $f$ at $x$" for a point $x$ of a manifold $M$, from the function $h$ described in condition M: you define $f(a) = h^{-1}(a, 0)$.

You can write/prove an analogous theorem for a point in the boundary of a manifold with boundary:

Given a diffeomorphism 
$$
h : U \subset \mathbb R^n \to V \subset \mathbb R^n
$$
such that 
\begin{align}
h(U \cap M)& = V \cap (H^k \times \{0\})\\
& = \{ y \in V \mid y^k \ge 0 \
\text{ and } y^{k+1} = \cdots = y^m = 0 \}
\end{align}
there's an open set $W' \subset \mathbb R^k$ and a function 
\begin{align}
f: W' \to \mathbb R^n
\end{align}
such that

1. $f(W' \cap H^k) = M \cap U$,
2. $f'(y)$ has rank $k$ for each $y \in W'$, and
3. $f^{-1}: f(W) \to W'$ is continuous.

The restriction of $f$ to $W = W' \cap H^k$ is called a *coordinate system* at $x$.

(Note that this is the definition of a coordinate system for a point of the *boundary* $\partial M$, *not* the interior of $M$, for which the definition following theorem 5.2 applies.)

The proof is essentially the same as the proof of 5.2, so I won't write it out.

So when Spivak writes, on page 119,

"If $f: W \to \mathbb R^n$ is a coordinate system with $W \subset H^k$ and $f(0) = x$, then only one of these ...."

he means that $f$ is a function like the one I've described above, not like the one from theorem 5.2.

I have to agree here: it would have been nice if he'd taken the time to write this out (or at least make it a HW problem!).

Comment: This makes it even worse, as then we cannot suppose to have a coordinate map $f : W \to \mathbb R^n$ at all, as this is just proved for manifolds????? So how does he came about to suppose that there exists one, and even if it does it would lead to the same contradictions as I noted??? Btw for the mathematical objects, they all satisfy the reverse relation, a field is a skew-field, a manifold is a manifold-with-boundary.

Comment: See my post-comment additions in the answer.

Comment: Also: you may be a little overoptimistic in your characterization of definitions in mathematics. For instance, "homogeneous coordinates" for real projective spaces are not coordinates in the usual sense (the dimension of one of the spaces is wrong), but ordinary coordinates on real projective spaces are not homogeneous coordinates either.

Comment: So you say $f = h^{-1}$? But look at Theorem 5.2. on page 111, there it is explicitly said what a coordinate function is, it is something weaker then the $h$ from (M) or (M'). But also with the $h$ from (M') the condition $W \subseteq H^k$ for $W$ open in $R^n$ would give that $f(W) \cap \partial M = \emptyset$ as $W \cap \partial H^k = \emptyset$ because diffeo's have to map boundary points to boundary points and vice versa??

Comment: I was sloppy; I've edited slightly (and so was Spivak, or at least  very terse).

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for the detailed answer!