# Question on the definition of tangent space at boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm going thought Spivak's 'Calculus On Manifolds' and I am bit confused with certain things in the definition of outward normal unit vector.

For the notation. With $v_{p}$ Spivak denotes the tangent vector $v$ at the point $p$, for a function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable on $A$ we have $f_{\ast}(v_p):=(Df(p)(v))_{f(p)}$ and for a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ he denotes by $[v_1,\ldots,v_n]$ the orientation of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.

Spivak [defines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLQqN.png) coordinate systems for manifolds wich then he uses in the [definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToZlr.png) of tangent space. He does not define coordinate systems on manifolds with boundaries but, nevertheless, he uses them in the [definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFiNh.png) of outward normal unit vectors. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708763/question-on-the-definition-of-outward-normal-vector-from-spivak-calculus-on-man) I read how to extend the definition of coordinate systems to manifolds with boundary but I haven't been able to extend the definition of tangent space to points in the boundary. How do we do that? Also, why is the tangent space $\partial M_{x}$ a subspace of $M_{x}$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manifolds with boundary, the coordinate condition should just be modified slightly, taking $W$ to be an open subset of $H^k = \{(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in \mathbb{R}^k : x_k\ge 0\}$, a half space in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is diffeomorphic to the interior of $H^k$, you get the interior points of $M$ using $W$ contained in the interior of $H^k$, and you get the boundary points of $M$ by using $W$ which intersect the boundary of $H^k$. You might ask what it means for a function $f:W \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to be smooth if $W \subset H^k$ has boundary points. It simply means there is an open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ with $V \cap H^k = W$ and an extension $f_V:V\to \mathbb{R}^n$ which is smooth and which restricts to $f$ on $W$, i.e., $f_V|_W = f$. Then the tangent space is similar to before, taking the image of the derivative of the extension, i.e., if $a\in \partial W$ and $f(a) = x \in \partial M$, then $M_x = (f_V)_*(\mathbb{R}^k_a)$.

Now, let's keep the notation $a\in \partial W$ and $f(a) = x \in \partial M$. We have $\partial W = W \cap \partial H^k$, and let's define $g:\partial W \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $g=f|_{\partial W}$. This is a local coordinate system for $\partial M$ at $x$, identifying $\partial H^k$ with $\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ in the natural way. You'll see that the Jacobian of $g$ at $a$ is just the Jacobian of $f_V$ at $a$ without the $k^{\small\text{th}}$ column. That's one way you can see that $(\partial M)_x = g_*(\mathbb{R}^{k-1}_a)$ is a subspace of $M_x$, and there are less coordinate-reliant ways to say it, too, but this is pretty concrete.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped.